# jquery combobox compare

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox, compare

I´m trying to compare values from an array with values in a combobox in jquery but with no success.

I have an array this way: (value 1,value 2,...) names separated with `,` (Example: `john smith,peter pan,`). On the other hand a combobox with values from a localstorage appended dynamically this way

```
 $('select[name="selectListMenu1"]').append( new Option(nombre.fname + " " + nombre.lname) );
```

This gives me a final name like 'John smith' and I append it to the combo.

Now I want to compare each name in the array with each name in the combobox and get selected in the combobox the names that matches.

```
var summary3 = (elnombre.proycontac).split(","); // split the names to compare
var p1 = summary3.length                         // get the number of names to compare
$('[name="selectListMenu1"] ').each(function(){           //from here i get lost 
       for (a=0; a<=p1-2; a++) { 
              if ($(this).text())=== summary3[a] {
              // select the name in combobox
              }
       }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$.map(summary3, function(elem, i) {
  $('select[name="selectListMenu1"] option[text="' + elem + '"]').attr('selected', true);
});
```

I put an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sje397/byDBB/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Set the selected attribute if you matched the text:

```
if ($(this).text() === summary3[a]) {
    $(this).attr('selected', true);
}
```